# IAR embedded Workbench for ARM MK60DN512VLQ10

Tags: iar, map-files

I have a question about the .map file generated in IAR embedded workbench.

I'm working with MK60DN512VLQ10 that have 512 KB of flash memory and 128 KB RAM.

Which of the below is stored in Flash and which on RAM?

*158 852 bytes of readonly  code memory

   18 446 bytes of readonly  data memory

   22 532 bytes of readwrite data memory*

This is the total memory usage or it changes in run time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends somewhat on your linker configuration but given a normal linker configuration the readonly memory is placed in flash and the readwrite memory is placed in RAM. The answer to the second question also depends on the linker configuration but under typical conditions the readwrite number includes both the block containing the c stack and the block reserved for the heap.